# Google Apps Script - Format value with 4 digits

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a variable which needs to be formatted into a 4 digit format,

i.e. 4 would be 0004, or 38 would be 0038

I've tried using getNumberFormat as below but this gives me no luck. Looking around I'm struggling to find a clean solution to this?

```js
var stringVal = 38;
var prettyVal = stringVal.getNumberFormat('0000');

worksheet.getRange(row+1, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).setValue("GL"+prettyVal);
```

EDIT - It needs to be formatted before being placed into my spreadsheet - since I'll append the string 'GL' before the value to form the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```js
    var stringVal = 38;
      var format = "0000"
      var prettyVal = stringVal.toString().length < 4 ? format.slice(stringVal.toString().length) + stringVal.toString() : stringVal ;
      console.log(prettyVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to a spreadsheet.  Once you have placed the value in a cell or cells you can setNumberFormat.

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1");
range.setValue(38);
range.setNumberFormat("000#");
```

Comment: Yep eventually it'll be added to a sheet, but since I'll later append a string before the value it needs to be formatted before being placed into the cell